# how to navigate between components in Laravel using dynamic component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a little project using Laravel and VueJs,  I'm also using dynamic component in my blade template.

I would like to know home can I navigate between pages(components) since I'm not using vue-router.

this is my code :

```
methods: {
register(url){
  Csrf.getCookie().then(() => {
    User.register(url, this.form)
    .then(() => {
      // how can i redirect the user since i'm not using vue router / should i use vue router ? 
    })
    .catch(error => {
      
    });
  })
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your choices are pretty much either:

- Use vue-router, including its element on a single Blade view and then navigating between Vue routes with `<router-link>` or `this.$router.push()`
- Use a single Vue component per Blade view in Laravel, navigating between them with a standard `<a href>` link

Answer (score 0):

With Nova 4, you can use `Nova.visit("/your/link")` in VueJs to allow Nova to change the page.